# Python allowing word input

Tags: python, string, terminal, integer

I am having trouble allowing users to type anything other than integers because doing so will make the programme crash and not print a piece of text I intended. 
[image: **Click me to view**]

This is the programme in terminal. 
[image: **Click me to view**]

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual code. Don't just link to pictures - it's annoying and not necessary.

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input` for python 2!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use raw_input() for python 2.x

```
guess = raw_input()
```

Also the code

```
elif: #Need help here!
```

Is not syntactically valid - it needs a condition clause.  But looking at your code, you can probably remove the "elif:" down to the "break", since it just replicates what's below it.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 6 & 20 you should use

```
print 'No its '+str(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
import sys

# Python version compatibility shim
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange
else:
    # Python 3.x
    inp = input
    rng = range

TRIES = 10

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Math Challenge!")
    correct = 0
    for m in rng(1, TRIES + 1):
        n = randint(1, 16)
        answer = m * n
        guess = inp("What is {} x {}? ".format(m, n))
        try:
            guess = int(guess)
            if guess == answer:
                print("That's right")
                correct += 1
            else:
                print("Sorry, it's actually {}".format(answer))
        except ValueError:
            # guess is not an int value
            guess = guess.strip().lower()
            if guess == "skip":
                print("Skipping...")
                continue
            elif guess == "stop":
                print("Stopping...")
                break
    print("You got {} correct out of {}!".format(correct, TRIES))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```